# Gradle and Jenkins setup to auto deploy java project on different Environments like DEV,Stage and Prod

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

need to setup gradle and jenkins to deploy jar/war/ear on different environment DEV/STAGE or PROD and It should be one touch process like click a button to "deploy on Stage" also how to set different environment configuration so it should take all configuration(like host name, password, db connection etc.) depend on selected environment.

Comment: Could you please describe your environment a little more detailed? Do you already have a  working deployment process? Is it just a plain scp or do you bootstrap your server using chef/puppet? 
Is it your main objective how to deal with the different credentials?

Comment: we are using Linux environment for deploying jar and currently we are doing manual deployment and it's a plain SCP no chef or puppet.
Main object is deploy on different servers like i have mentioned in que DEV,STAGE and Prod env.

Comment: Hanu, can you explain how you solved this setup?

Comment: For solving this we used docker images.